# wrapfigure problem: text over figure

Tags: floats, errors, wrapfigure

I am a relatively new LaTeX user, so bear with me.  I am using `wrapfigure` to present figures in a grant application (read: space is at a premium).  All of a sudden, one of my figures is being presented *under* the text.  I have done a lot of debugging including replacing the file from another figure file (still has the problem) but putting the original figure into other analogous code reproduces the problem with different code.  Changing the file to a JPG from a PDF doesn't help.

Anyways, I've spent several hours on this and any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've posted the relevant code.

[image]

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}

\begin{center}

\vspace{-38pt}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{infantpilotresults-cropped.pdf}

\vspace{-27pt}

\caption{\emph{Six month-olds' looking to unexpected visual omissions.}}

\vspace{-15pt}

\label{figure:prelim1results} 

\end{center}

\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Is there a page break near the problematic figure?

Comment: Not an explicitly forced one. e.g. \newpage

Comment: Please try to remove the `\vspace`. It  might be that the total of the `\vspace` is more than the height of the figure.

Comment: THanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that doesn't help.  I took out all of the vspace and it shifted the figure but just behind the text.

Comment: @LaurenLEmberson pagebreaks (even non explicit ones) can be problematic if they occur in the place where the wrapfigure is supposed to appear. Try changing the wrapfigure to another location and see if that solves the problem; also, remove the `\vspace` commands.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina,  moving the text to a different location (away from the page break) works (even leaving in the vspace).  Thanks!  So I just can't have a figure there I guess.

Comment: Yes; it is mentioned in the package documentation: "The environment should be placed so as to not run over a page break." I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: To add, I was working on a poster using the baposter class. For me, wrapfigure worked by putting it at the beginning of the headerbox and on the left side instead of the right side.

Answer (score 10):

After the comments to the original question it is clear that the problem was caused by a page break. Pagebreaks (even non explicit ones) can be problematic if they occur in the place where the wrapfigure is supposed to appear. The `wrapfig` package documenatation mentions this explicitly:

> The environment should be placed so as to not run over a page break.

Moving the `wrapfigure` environment to another location fixes the problem.

As a side note, instead of using the `center` environment it could be better to use the `\centering` command; also, perhaps you might want to reconsider the use of the `\vspace` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I have found there is also a problem if the text next to wrapfigure starts a new paragraph. You can fix this if, at that paragraph break, you change

```
end of new paragraph.

Start of new paragraph ...
```

to

```
end of new paragraph.\hfill\break\indent Start of new paragraph ...
```

It will look exactly like a new paragraph, but latex won't think it has started another paragraph, and wrapfigure magically works again.

You can put the Start on a new line, just don't include a blank line in between. Or to make it easier to see where your pseudo-paragraphs are, put a line starting with `%` in between, latex won't see that as a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the cause was different. I had

```
{\hskip \parindent}
```

at the beginning of one of my paragraphs, removing it fixed the problem.

I tried replacing it with

```
\hspace{\parindent}
```

but that also caused the `wrapfigure` to be misplaced and overlap the text.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that defining the spacing for that area of text to cause the text to properly wrap, especially for figures that have a transparent background. Use `\begin{spacing}{1.0}` ending with `\end{spacing}`, for example. You will need the setspace package: `\usepackage{setspace}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome! I'm not quite sure that this is the problem the author of the original question had. It would be great if you could expand on your answer to show an example (as minimal as possible) where this trick helped you!